# Segmentation in c

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, c-strings

Looking to confirm that a string is a digit but getting a segmentation fault on the below - no errors when compiling:

```
for (int i=0; argv[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (isdigit(argv[i]) != 1)
    {
        printf("FAIL %s\n", argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("PASS %s\n", argv[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `isdigit()` takes a single character argument, not a string. Also, never use "== 1" or "!= 1" when testing truth. All values other than 0 are true.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you are getting no warnings when doing `isdigit(argv[i])`.

Comment: The `isXXXX()` family of functions returns a non-zero value if the result is `true`. So if `isdigit()` returns `2` meaning a digit was passed, your test will fail, because you will only accept `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
int success = argv[1][0] != '\0';

for ( size_t i = 0; success && argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++ )
{
    success = isdigit( ( unsigned char )argv[1][i] ) != 0;
}

if ( !success )
{
    printf( "FAIL %s\n", argv[1] );
}
else
{
    printf( "PASS %s\n", argv[1] );
}
```

That is you want to check that the first command line parameter represents a number.

Comment: Seems strange that you'd want the string printed N times if it's correct... but well, I can only speculate.

Comment: Thanks Vlad - that outputs exactly what I'm after. What does 'size_t' do? And why do I need to do 'argv[1][i]' and not just 'argv[i]'? I've only spent a couple of weeks on C and trying to understand what I'm inputting

Comment: @JackHartley size_t is unsigned integer type used to store object sizes or indices. argv[i] is a pointer to a string that specifies a parameter. If you want to scan the string you have to use a second index.